# Making concrete return types generic

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Consider the following two methods, which are essentially copy and pasted versions of one another

```
public static List<Book> GetSubSet(List<Book> incomingList)
        {
            List<Book> returnList = new List<Book>();
            Random r = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter size of random subset: ");
            int randomInt = 0;
            int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (size > incomingList.Count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Size too large, enter smaller subset: ");
                size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            while (returnList.Count < size)
            {
                randomInt = r.Next(incomingList.Count);
                if (!returnList.Contains(incomingList[randomInt]))
                {
                    returnList.Add(incomingList[randomInt]);
                }
            }
            return returnList;
        }

 public static List<Pet> GetSubSet(List<Pet> incomingList)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            List<Pet> returnList = new List<Pet>();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter random subset size: ");
            int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (size > incomingList.Count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Size too large.  Enter random subset size: ");
                size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            while (returnList.Count < size)
            {
                int randomInt = r.Next(incomingList.Count);
                if (!returnList.Contains(incomingList[randomInt]))
                {
                    returnList.Add(incomingList[randomInt]);
                }
            }

            return returnList;
        }
```

Obviously this isn't very OO and I would like to have a single method that could take care of whatever type.  I don't want to use inheritance because there's no logical connection or between books and dogs, and I don't want the types contained because containment doesn't make sense either.  So we're left with an interface.  Something like

```
 interface ISubset
    {

        IEnumerable<T> GetSubset();
    }
```

I've seen but I don't know how to make the angle brackets accept any generic type.  How can I make the IEnumerable type generic so that I can implement the GetSubset method on any class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it generic:

```
    public static List<T> GetSubSet<T>(List<T> incomingList)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        List<T> returnList = new List<T>();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter random subset size: ");
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        while (size > incomingList.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Size too large.  Enter random subset size: ");
            size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        while (returnList.Count < size)
        {
            int randomInt = r.Next(incomingList.Count);
            if (!returnList.Contains(incomingList[randomInt]))
            {
                returnList.Add(incomingList[randomInt]);
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make the `GetSubSet` method generic:

```
public static List<T> GetSubSet<T>(List<T> incomingList)
{
    var returnList = new List<T>();
    Random r = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter size of random subset: ");
    int randomInt = 0;
    int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    while (size > incomingList.Count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Size too large, enter smaller subset: ");
        size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    while (returnList.Count < size)
    {
        randomInt = r.Next(incomingList.Count);
        if (!returnList.Contains(incomingList[randomInt]))
        {
            returnList.Add(incomingList[randomInt]);
        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

and then you could use it like this:

```
List<Pet> incomingList = ...
List<Pet> result = GetSubSet(incomingList);
```

Notice that we haven't specified the type when calling the `GetSubSet` method which is possible thanks to the compiler generic type inference for methods. This is equivalent to:

```
List<Pet> result = GetSubSet<Pet>(incomingList);
```

but the compiler is able to infer that.

Comment: I didn't know that this was possible without using an interface.  Thanks!

Comment: It's possible by using generics. You still get compile-time safety which is great.

Comment: This may not be the best avenue for the question but I'll give it a shot: Why can't I implement an interface of type IEnumerable<T> without getting an error that T isn't a defined type?

Comment: Of course that you can. You just need to make this interface generic.

Comment: Now I see what I did, I didn't mark the Interface itself as generic, only the return type of the method.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Have one method, and make the method itself generic.

```
public static List<T> GetSubSet<T>(List<T> incomingList)
```